# Convert a list of strings into individual string in Python

Tags: python

A newbie question for which I apologize if it's basic.
I have a set, myset, that is filled by reading an csv file see below printed representation.

```
set(['value1', 'value2'])
```

The number of elements on the set is arbitrary, depending upon the read file. I want to add entries on a csv file using the individual elements of the set. I've tried:

```
    file_row = ['#Entry','Time', str(myset), 'cpu usage']
    print file_row
    filewriter.writerow(file_row)
```

However the output I get is:

```
#Entry,Time,"set(['value1', 'value2'])",cpu usage
```

where I actually wanted

```
#Entry,Time,value1,value2,cpu usage.
```

Can you suggest how to get my desired result ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could approach this as follows:

```
file_row = ['#Entry','Time'] # start with pre-myset elements
file_row.extend(myset) # add on myset
file_row.append('cpu usage') # add final item
```

Note that using a `set` means the *order* of elements will also be arbitrary.

Comment: It works fine.
Thanks for the heads-up on the set ordering. I need to keep that in mind.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it all in one line:

`file_row = ['#Entry','Time'] + [x for x in myset] + ['cpu usage']`